# how to auto fill textfield in java using combo box

Tags: java, jtextfield

```
   c.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Object selected = c.getSelectedItem();
            s = (String)selected;
            tf1.setText(s);                     
            }   
    });
```

when setting text it gives error attempt to mutate in notification. besides this if i write label.setText(s); it gives no error and set text according to selected item in combo... c is JComboBox object

Comment: c is JComboBox object

Comment: Add that to the question

Comment: Seriously, question is not clear

Comment: i want to set the text of the TextField object according to the selected item in comboBox.. is it clear now ?

Comment: Okay but it sets to the of the selected `jcombobox` item.

Comment: tf1.setText(s); this line does not set text according to the selected item

Comment: rather give Attempt to mutation error while when i use label object in place of text field it gives no error ad works fine for Jlabel object

Comment: do you have any code for it i.e., when someone select an item in combo box its value is appeared in textField

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. Are you sure `tf1` has been instantiated well as in `JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(10);` and added to the JFrame.

Comment: Can you present [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code of your class.